# What is %c equivalent for String.Format in .NET?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I tried to find a way to port "%c" formatting in printf style function with .NET language, but failed. For example, how can I write:

```
char code = 'a';
sprintf(text,"oops! %c",code);
```

in C++/CLI I tried some but they did not give me 'a'!

**EDIT:**

First I tried to format some value to character 'a' or 'b' or 'c'... Environment is VisualStudio 2008, CLI/CPP, .NET 3.5. I wrote test code to show what I did.

```
String^ text;
char    charC = 'a';
text = String::Format("(1) Oops! {0}",charC);
OutputDebugString(text);
char    charV = 1;
text = String::Format("(2) Oops! {0}",charV + 0x60);
OutputDebugString(text);
text = String::Format("(3) Oops! {0}",(char)(charV + 0x60));
OutputDebugString(text);
int intV = 1;
text = String::Format("(4) Oops! {0}",(char)(intV + 0x60));
OutputDebugString(text);
```

Result is different from I expected.

```
(1) Oops! 97
(2) Oops! 97
(3) Oops! 97
(4) Oops! 97
```

Above code seems working differently from code suggested by others. And I feel sorry I should have stated what I did in more detail at the first time.

If we have just {0} to format variable, we have no choice to select making it to character like 'a' or number like '97'. And I failed to get 'a', I wanted to ask how to do it.

**EDIT2:**

As suggested by comment, I changed 'char' to 'Char' like this;

```
String^ text;
Char    charC = 'a';
text = String::Format("(1) Oops! {0}",charC);
OutputDebugString(text);
Char    charV = 1;
text = String::Format("(2) Oops! {0}",charV + 0x60);
OutputDebugString(text);
text = String::Format("(3) Oops! {0}",(Char)(charV + 0x60));
OutputDebugString(text);
int intV = 1;
text = String::Format("(4) Oops! {0}",(Char)(intV + 0x60));
OutputDebugString(text);
```

And I got;

```
(1) Oops! a
(2) Oops! 97
(3) Oops! a
(4) Oops! a
```

So 'Char' instead of 'char' seems working.

Comment: "*I tried some but they did not give me 'a'*" - what exactly have you tried? Show some of your attemps then someone can point to your errors.

Comment: .NET doesn't use formatting specifiers like this at all - `string.Format` simply uses numbered arguments with optional format specifiers. In case of `char`, there's no point of using those - `string.Format("oops! {0}", code)` will do.

Comment: Your code is not C#, but C++/CLI; you're question doesn't seem to relate to C# at all.

Comment: @Setsu, I'm sorry I thought there is no difference between C# and C++/CLI for this question and I stated C# for example. And I did not mentioned I tried using C# language.

Comment: Use `Char` instead of `char`.

Comment: @Hans, Yes your suggestion worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `char` keyword keeps its original meaning in the C and C++ languages, it is a 8-bit type in MSVC++, the .NET Framework does not have an equivalent character type so String::Format() treats it like an alias for System::SByte.  An integral type so you see the integer value and not a character.

.NET uses utf-16 encoded Unicode, System::Char is a 16-bit type.  In MSVC++ that matches the `wchar_t` keyword.  Which you can use directly, or use `Char` instead of `char`.